# Error showing support.v7.AppCompatDialogFragment using show() method

Tags: android, android-support-library, appcompatdialogfragment

I am using v7 support AppCompatDialogFragment in my app

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment;

public class LoginDialogFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

}
```

Throughout the app I am using default `Fragment` and `FragmentManager` and **NOT** `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` or `adroid.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```

Now the problem is I want to show the dialog from an Activity by calling the method

```
public void show(@NotNull android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager,
                 java.lang.String tag)
```

Which **does not accept**  `android.app.FragmentManager` as parameter.

So I can't call

```
LoginDialogFragment loginDialogFragment = new LoginDialogFragment();
loginDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

HOW TO SHOW DIALOG NOW ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the native `Fragment` support with [AppCompatDialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialogFragment.html). In fact, if you check closer the import of `AppCompatDialogFragment`, you will find out that it comes from the support library. You have to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`. Like

```
loginDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

everything from AppCompat* is from the support library

Comment: My activity is only showing `getFragmentManager()` and not showing `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: Let  your  `Activity` extend `AppCompatActivity`. There is a reason if they all share the same prefix name ?

Comment: Its already extending `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`. No such method `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: then you have also access to getSupportFragmentManager. If you import it

Comment: How ??? May be I need to extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. But  I don't want support for 3.0 devices my Min SKD = 11. Why to use support Fragment ??

Comment: Why are you using `AppCompatDialogFragment.` then ?

Comment: I fail to see why this answer was voted down, in fact it is probably already too good of an answer for this nonsensical question...

Comment: Puzzling... Its from v7 support library. So I thought Its the latest and will use Material design similar to `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`. Its not like that ??? Please teach me.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Blackbelt

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void show(@NotNull android.app.FragmentManager manager, java.lang.String tag)
```