# How to call AppCompatDialogFragment from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, appcompatdialogfragment

I have a `class` that extends from `AppCompatDialogFragment`

```
public class SendLetterDialogFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
public static SendLetterDialogFragment newInstance() {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    SendLetterDialogFragment fragment = new SendLetterDialogFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.send_letter_dialog_fragment, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}
```

}

When I show it from `Activity`(using `getSupportFragmentManager) it works. But  I can't  use  this method in Fragment:

```
SendLetterDialogFragment fragment = SendLetterDialogFragment.newInstance();
    fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "lol");
```

I've read some related issues like  this
[Error showing support.v7.AppCompatDialogFragment using show() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270720/error-showing-support-v7-appcompatdialogfragment-using-show-method)  but they didn't help me.

How to show `AppCompatDialogFragment` from the `Fragment`?

P.S. The activity, where the fragment places extends `AppComtapActivity`. 
Calling `getChildFragmentManager`  instead of `getFragmentManager` doesn't help.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt3yk.jpg)

**EDIT**

I didn't solve this problem, so I decided to create dialog with `AlertDialog.Builder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Look at the screen on the bottom of the post. The same error  with `getChildFragmentManager`

Comment: make sure you import android.support.v4.app.Fragment insted of android.app.Fragment

Comment: You are right. I use `android.app.Fragment`, because I can't use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` while using `NavigationView`

Comment: NavigationView you can also use android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: use android.support.v4.app.Fragment and fragmentmanager ignore android.app.Fragment and fragmentmanager

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. I can't you `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` for `NavigationView` directly. I showed you screen, buddy :)

Comment: thank you. Just found another way to call custom dialog. Unfortunately your advices didn't help :(